# yii2 gridview toggle column

Tags: gridview, yii2

I am new to yii2. and learning it slowly. 
I am using yii2 gridview in my project I want to show hide columns dynamically. 
requires something like this  [https://datatables.net/examples/api/show_hide.html =>demo is given in this link] but cant understand how to do this? can anybody help?

code=>

```
<?php 

    $gridColumns = [
                     ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
                     ['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn'],  
[
                    'header' => '<input type="checkbox"> Name',//onclick of this checkbox show / hide the column 
                    'attribute'=>'name',                                          
                ],   
                    'company_mail', 
                    'no_employees',
                    'email:email', 
                    .
                    .
                    .];
            echo GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'filterModel' => $searchModel,
            'columns' => $gridColumns,
    ]); 
    ?>
```

also tried like this=> `'visible'=>false,`
but it hides permanently... where to add if() condition ??

how to solve this ..can anyone solve?

also [[Toggle Column visibility in Yii Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27084841/toggle-column-visibility-in-yii-framework][it) is for cgridview can i use this one in yii2]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to hide column Yii2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46971647/is-it-possible-to-hide-column-yii2)

Comment: I tried it but not working... also where we have that checkbox given in that answer

Comment: Setting unknown property: yii\grid\SerialColumn::width,vAlign...getting this error

Comment: 'visible'=>false, how to add javascript for this..to hode the row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done using JavaScript or jQuery.
The [example](https://datatables.net/examples/api/show_hide.html) you gave uses jQuery.
If you inspect the page, you can find all bits of code you need to get this working.

Links that toggle columns have `data-column` attribute which contains the number of the column (starting with 0):

```
<a class="toggle-vis" data-column="0">Name</a>
```

The page contains script, which toggles the column by it's number (using DataTables plug-in):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //getting the table that we will be working with
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "scrollY": "200px",
        "paging": false
    } );

    $('a.toggle-vis').on( 'click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Get the column by number
        var column = table.column( $(this).attr('data-column') );

        // Toggle the visibility
        column.visible( ! column.visible() );
    } );
} );
```

Here is a simple script that will work with previously mentioned links (in this case - **starting with 1**) and any table (just switch `#example` with your gridview's id):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.toggle-vis').on('click', function(e) {
        var column = $(this).attr('data-column');
        $('#example th:nth-child(' + column + '), #example td:nth-child(' + column + ')').toggle();
    });
});
```

Give gridview table id:

```
echo GridView::widget([
       'tableOptions' => ['id' => 'example'],
       'class' => 'table table-striped table-bordered'
])
```

Comment: <a class="toggle-vis" data-column="0">Name</a> where do I define this tag in gridview ..... and which/whose id in place "#example" ...

Comment: @Goli <a> tags for colum toggling are not defined in gridview, you just add those to the page before the gridview, for example `<p><a class="toggle-vis" data-column="1">Name</a></p>`. You can specify the id of your gridview using id property of gridview (`'id' => 'myid'`) and then use that value instead of 'example'.

Comment: [
                        'header' => '<input type="checkbox"> Name',                        
                        'attribute'=>'name',
                    'options' => [ 'id' => 'myid'],
                      
                    ],   ......tried in this way but not working.. is it right?? and wrote same js as you have given in answer with myid instead of example..

Comment: @Goli You need to add id to gridview property, not column. Links that toggle columns need to  defined outside of the gridview [as in this CodePen](https://codepen.io/eggnukes/pen/ZaGgga)